# mutable field with overloaded assignment operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, mutable

I have a C++ class field that is declared mutable.  When it was of type double, I could modify it in a const method with no problem.  But when I switched its type to a class in which operator= is overloaded, I got the error that this overloaded operator= does not take a const pointer to this.  Is this a gcc bug, or a language quirk?

Comment: Please show some code (as little as possible) that reproduces the problem ... and tell us what version of gcc you're using

Comment: Can't replicate neither with gcc 4.3.4 nor gcc 4.7.0: http://ideone.com/0mvlJi

Answer (score 1):

When you suspect a compiler bug you should say which compiler version you are using. You know, bugs are killed every day.

Anyway, this code compiles fine with GCC 4.6.3:

```
struct A
{
    void operator=(int)
    {
    }
};

struct B
{
    mutable A a;
};

int main()
{
    const B b;
    b.a = 42;
}
```

But, of course, this does not (it this your case):

```
struct A
{
    mutable int m;
    void operator=(int x)
    {
        m = x;
    }
};

struct B
{
    A a;
};

int main()
{
    const B b;
    b.a = 42;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mutable` has the effect that `const` qualification on the implicit object parameter is nullified (**5.2.5 Class member access [expr.ref]**, paragraph 4):

> [...] If `E2` is declared to be a `mutable` member, then the type of `E1.E2`
>   is “*vq12* `T`”. If `E2` is not declared to be a `mutable` member, then the type of `E1.E2` is “*cq12 vq12* `T`”.

5.2.5 applies for implicit member access per 9.3.1p3:

> When an *id-expression* [...] is used in a member of class `X` [...] the *id-expression* is transformed into a class member access expression using `(*this)` as the *postfix-expression* to the left of the `.` operator.

So in your `const` method the `mutable` member is not (observed to be) const-qualified.  Your observed behaviour must be the result of a compiler bug.

Comment: Assuming only that OP's description is perfectly accurate ...